# Screenshots on Mac Monitor Widget

Tags: website-design, monitor

This may be an odd question. I can't bring up an example now that I'm looking for it, but often, I have seen software displayed on a Mac monitor on a site in a screenshot. When you click on the monitor the screenshot enlarges so you can get a better look.

This can be replicated by some photoshop and some JavaScript, however, I was wondering if this is a common widget.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably better suited question for Stack Exchange. There are a ton of javascript libraries to do this... litebox, thickbox, highslide, jquery, fancybox...

Comment: I'm confused, what are you actually asking?  Are you asking how to do this or just if it's common?  You are a well versed and well known javascript developer so I'm pretty sure your not asking how to implement this effect.

Comment: Thank you, @Chris. I'm asking if there is an accepted way to do this, as it is so common. I'm going to use lightbox as it seems there isn't.

Comment: I have seen this too but can't really comment on the developer side of it. From a graphic point of view it's a merge of 2 screenshots, the app and the empty desktop. Here is an example: http://www.realmacsoftware.com/courier/

Answer (score 1):

There's no common widget out there but there are a LOT of variants of the old lightbox effect you are referring to. If you want to stick to the Adobe suite, there are widgets for Dreamweaver but I've never touched them. There's a forum post here -> http://forums.adobe.com/thread/37212

If you were interested in comparing all of the different libraries designed to do the lightbox effect, there's an excellent resource at http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/ which compares the features, costs and technology of a whooooole bunch of them.

Personally, I like ColorBox from http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox